# Windows Hidden Screen Capture API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm creating a Windows 10 app that requires screen capture. What is the best way to capture screens including hidden ones(with SetWindowDisplayAffinity)?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/09/16/new-ways-to-do-screen-capture/

Comment: @Geoffrey. Can these methods capture hidden windows?

Comment: *"including hidden ones(with SetWindowDisplayAffinity)"* - Why would Windows invest in an API call (`SetWindowDisplayAffinit`) and then supply an API that ignores that API call's effects?

Comment: By design, hidden windows do not get any WM_PAINT events, etc... as such they are never drawn/updated and there is nothing to capture even if you could.

Comment: @geo The OP isn't talking about hidden windows. The OP is talking about windows that had [explicitly requested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) to not get included in a screen capture, even if fully visible.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, missed that part. The only method I know of to capture such windows is to use NVIDIA NvFBC if it's available to you, it's able to bypass this as it's a driver-level capture. You do still however have to force desktop composition by creating a transparent window or NvFBC will just give you black areas also.

Comment: @Geoffrey I have seen some applications which can capture hidden windows. When I try I'm getting a black screen.

Comment: [Desktop Composition is always on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/desktop-window-manager-is-always-on) starting with Windows 8. In other words: There is no supported version of Windows where desktop composition can be disabled.

Comment: The driver can optimize this in such a way as to prevent NvFBC from being able to capture these windows still, using a transparent window forces the driver to use a method that still allows capture. See my project Looking Glass where we do this: https://github.com/gnif/LookingGlass/blob/master/host/platform/Windows/src/force_compose.c

Comment: @IInspectable. Yeah that's what my requirement is. So is there any unofficial way I can capture these hidden windows and stream?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. That's the whole point of the flag. If it was trivial to subvert, the flag would be useless.

The only way you can do this would be to *clear* the flag, which would require that you have the ability to execute arbitrary code in the process that owns the window in question.